# how to grep a log and print multiple string or text from a log

Tags: unix, awk, sed, scripting, cut

```html
ERROR|2017-04-04 06:27:20|ID=15098|ST=2018-04-0406:27:21|TYPE=Log|LOG=6|OBJECT=NoticeBService|T_TIME=10|REQUEST_MSG=<Envelope><Header><ns11:messageId>184745460</ns11:messageId><ns11:messageDateTime>2018-04-13T11:27:21Z</ns11:messageDateTime></Header></Envelope>|RESPONSE_MSG=<Envelope><Header><m:messageId>184460</m:messageId><m:messageDateTimeStamp>2018-04-04T06:27:21-05:00</m:messageDateTimeStamp></m:trackingMessageHeader></m:wsMessageHeader></Header><Body><Fault><faultcode>Server.704</faultcode><detail><ns1:providerError><ns1:providerErrorCode>704</ns1:providerErrorCode><ns1:providerErrorText>business_rule_exception-Server.704: 'Active'status.</ns1:providerErrorText></ns1:providerError></detail></Fault></Body></Envelope>
```

I want to print from a test.log:
**OBJECT=NoticeBService
business_rule_exception-Server.704: 'Active'status.**

I used : sed -n '/providerErrorText/,/providerErrorText/p' | cut -d '|' -f 7 test.log

I getting output :
OBJECT=NoticeBService
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: extra characters after command

Comment: I tried using sed -n '/<ns1:providerErrorText>/,/</ns1:providerErrorText>/p' | cut -d '|' -f 7 test.log

Comment: I am getting output as -> OBJECT=NoticeBService
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: extra characters after command

Comment: I want BOLD String as output :->OBJECT=NoticeBService

Answer (score 0):

with `grep`

```
$ grep -oP 'OBJECT[^|]+|(?<=providerErrorText>)[^<]+' file

OBJECT=NoticeBService
business_rule_exception-Server.704: 'Active'status.
```

**Explanation**

> `OBJECT[^|]+` looking for the literal "OBJECT" and match until a pipe symbol
>
> `(?<=providerErrorText>)` look-behind, find the pattern but not capture
> `[^<]+` capture everything until the `<` sign
>
> `-oP` `o` is for outputting only the matched pattern, `P` for perl compatibility (for look-behind matching here).
>
> `pattern1|pattern2` is for either pattern1 or pattern2 match (it can be both).

Comment: if possible can you explain little brief how it works